# Re-updating an Android phone for test purposes?

Tags: samsung, updates, ota-update

For a network test, we require an Android phone to perform an OS update.
  We have a Nexus 6P and a Samsung Galaxy S8+.

The issue is that once we perform an update, it's updated, and no more updates can occur.

Is there a simple way to 'reverse' an update, and re-get the latest update?

Comment: Flash a factory image/firmware of an older version, although Samsung has bootloader levels that make the matter slightly more complicated.

Comment: @AndyYan yeah, was hoping there was a simpler method - the Samsung one especially is problematic :/

Comment: @AndyYan Please post that as an answer. Comments are not for answering the question.

Comment: @DanHulme I'm not sure if that's what OP is looking for, especially after he posted the reply above.

Comment: I think it's the only way to do what he's describing. If the OP is hoping for an easier answer too, that's fine.